# Cant access main parents callback function inside mongo query | cb is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, async.js

I am working with mongodb in sails js. we are using `async.auto` from `async.js`.

I am creating a new mongo connection for few reasons and firing `find` query to get the data, after retrieving data from db I want to call `cb` of `async.auto` to pass the error if any and the result using `cb(err, results)`. but I am getting an error saying `cb is not a function`.

**The Hierarchy is as below:**

`fun1(cb)` -> `Mongo.connect` -> `db.find(results)` -> `return cb(null, results)`

I cant share exact code for some reason but here is and example of my code

**Code:**

```
async.auto(
                {
                    fun1: function (cb) {
                           // my logic
                           return cb(null, true);
                    },
                    fun2: [
                        'fun1',
                        function (results, cb) {
                            const querySearch = {
                                id,
                            };

                            MongoClient.connect(url, async function (err, db) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.error(err);
                                    return cb(err, false);
                                }

                                await db
                                    .collection(colName)
                                    .find(
                                        querySearch,
                                        async function (err, results) {
                                            if (err) {
                                                console.error(err);
                                                return cb(err, false);
                                            }
                                            console.log(results);
                                            return cb(null, results); // Error: cb is not a function
                                        }
                                    );
                                db.close();
                            });
                        },
                    ],
                    fun3: [
                        'fun2',
                        function (results, cb) {
                           return cb(null, true);
                        },
                    ],
                },
                function (err, results) {
                    if(err){
                        console.error(err);
                        res.negotiate('Unexpected Error Occured!')
                    }

                    res.ok('Successfully');
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function should be the first parameter of the function.
Also, no need to declare the `find` callback `async`:

```
fun2: [
      'fun1',
      function (cb, results) {
        const querySearch = {
          id,
        };

        MongoClient.connect(url, async function (err, db) {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return cb(err, false);
          }

          await db
            .collection(colName)
            .find(querySearch, function (err, res) {
              if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return cb(err, false);
              }
              console.log(res);
              return cb(null, res); 
            });
          db.close();
        });
      },
    ],
```